# Can I set limit the maximum idle instances in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google App Engine flexible environment on PHP 7.2 application and we are using auto_scaling.
We occasionally  get traffic spikes, but App engine will always keep 4 instances running.
What settings to add to app.yaml to force App Engine to always keep only one idle instance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using App Engine Flex with auto scaling, you can't use the flag "max_idle_instances" in the app.yaml since this would give you an error; however, I would  advice you to set a ["max_num_instances"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling) in order to prevent you from starting too many instances during one of your spikes.

I would also advice you to check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SH5xRgemOJs) and [this other one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eUXUY7QFfAI), as they explain very well how to set up your app.yaml to optimize your scaling.

Hope you find this helpful!